# How do I add new list tile in order in Flutter? When I add new one it is added in random order

Tags: flutter, mobile

[Numbers should go 1,2,3 not like this[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrp98.jpg)

Comment: so simply `sort()` your `List`

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how your code look like but if you add a new item it will be at the top and the first item will be at bottom. the list doesn't care about the items value if its 1 or 2.

If you want them in order use `sort()` 
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/List/sort.html